# Kafka - more messages than expected after compact

Tags: apache-kafka

I have set log.retention.check.interval.ms in broker.properties to 1000.

I have created topic using following command:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic compact_topic --config cleanup.policy=compact --config segment.bytes=80 --config retention.bytes=150 --config max.compaction.lag.ms=1000
```

One-character message (one message package produced by kafka-console-producer.sh) seems to have 70 bytes.

New segments are properly created for each message. I've put 1 message with key "1" (1:1) and 3 messages with key "2" (2:A, 2:B, 2:C).

When compacting occurs there are 3 messages left (1:1, 2:B, 2:C) and also 3 un-empty segment files. One of the segments is active one. My question is why if the retention.bytes is set to 150 there are 3 not-empty segments instead of 2?

I can also add messages, and it will compact within a minute or 2 back to 3 messages. There are only 2 keys and 2 messages with the same key are preserved. This is an output after few more tries:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -topic compact_topic --from-beginning --property print.key=true --property key.separator=:
1:1
2:H
2:I
```

Comment: If you want only one of each key, build a KTable. Don't trust that the raw topic will always have unique keys. Also, with these settings, you're causing unnecessary load on the broker CPU/disk when you have lots of events

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thank you for the reply, but this is only a demo. I wanted to demonstrate a simplest example on how the topic will preserve the message "1" and delete "A" when I send "B". However, it wasn't deleting "A" even though the process of compacting was completed so I'm wondering why.

Comment: There are other properties related to compaction like min dirty-ratio, per segment. In my experience, it is never "take latest key", even though that's what the documentation may want you to think